# pagedown markdown converter is throwing exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, markdown, pagedown

I am using `pagedown` markdown to convert text to html. but in this file [node-pagedown.js](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/node-pagedown.js?r=8d4f4813346a3f0fd6741fb896d92eeb364bf298)
it throws error uncaught exception and the says `exports` is not defined. what can be wrong and where is this defined in the first place??